# gdb magic sauce to list contents of bitset? Actually it was my unique_ptr wrapper

Tags: gdb

[Blind as a bat, didn't see the unique_ptr for the trees]

So if I ask gdb to `p bitset` it helpfully tells me

```
$1 = std::unique_ptr<std::bitset<500000ul>> containing 0x67df80
```

And, if I follow that `x 0x67df80`

```
0x67df80:       0x0067e2b0
```

And `x /8b  0x0067e2b0`

```
0x67e2b0:       0xb7    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
```

Is there a magic combination that will get it [the command] all on one line, i.e. reusable?

Digging in the source offers member variable _M_w,

but `p bitset._M_w` just returns

```
There is no member or method named _M_w
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a magic combination that will get it all on one line, i.e. reusable?

It's not clear what you mean by "all on one line" (your output is *already* all on one line), or what you mean by reusable.

It's also not clear why you'd want to examine your bitset in terms of bytes (instead of `int`s or `long`s).

With GDB libstdc++ pretty printers installed, this program:

```
#include <bitset>

int main()
{
  std::bitset<5> b5;
  std::bitset<5000> b5000;

  b5[1] = 1;
  b5000[1] = 1;
  b5000[50] = 1;

  return 0;
}
```

when stopped on `return`, GDB produces the following output:

```
(gdb) p b5
$1 = std::bitset = {[1] = 1}
(gdb) p b5000
$2 = std::bitset = {[1] = 1, [50] = 1}
(gdb) p/r b5000
$3 = {<std::_Base_bitset<79ul>> = {_M_w = {1125899906842626, 0 <repeats 78 times>}}, <No data fields>}
(gdb) x/gx b5000._M_w
0x7fffffffdab0: 0x0004000000000002
```

**Update:**

> At present I only see `$1 = std::unique_ptr<std::bitset<500000ul>> containing 0x67df80`

This is because your problem is not printing `std::bitset`, it's printing `std::unique_ptr`. You want to *dereference* it.

(Sorry I missed this on first read, it's now obvious that your subject didn't match your actual question.)

Modifying the example like so:

```
#include <bitset>
#include <memory>

int main()
{
  auto b5 = std::make_unique<std::bitset<5>>();

  (*b5)[1] = 1;

  return 0;
}
```

Here is what I see:

```
(gdb) p b5
$1 = std::unique_ptr<std::bitset<5>> containing 0x613c20
(gdb) p *b5
$2 = std::bitset = {[1] = 1}
```

Coming back to:

> `p bitset._M_w` just returns `There is no member or method named _M_w`

also makes sense: `unique_ptr` doesn't have `_M_w`, `bitset` does. You want:

```
(gdb) p b5._M_t._M_t._M_head_impl->_M_w
$3 = 2
```

Comment: Perhaps I need thiose prettyprinters, thanks: That could be my magic sauce. At present I only see `$1 = std::unique_ptr<std::bitset<500000ul>> containing 0x67df80` which is pretty useless, yet something is clearly being done to make that happen.